# What's the point of the query_vars filter?

Tags: wp-query, filters

WordPress doesn't seem to support named parameters in a query string (like `?foo=123&bar=456`) unless you explicitly allow them by doing `add_filter('query_vars'...)`.  Why is this? What (presumably security-related) benefit is it supposed to offer?

I have an unusual setup with various custom code that pulls in page content from an external (non-WP) source, and I find it a bit tedious to have to tell WordPress about every parameter name I might be using.

[The docs say](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) "public query variables ... are built up when WP_Query instantiates, but fortunately are passed through a filter ‘query_vars‘". Why is it fortunate? A malicious visitor could add extra parameters to the URL, but so what?